# MongoDB Aggregation pipeline, update an existing elements in an array after string split

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**Sample Doc :**

```
{
  bioupdate: [
    {
      date: "02/03/2020",
      ts: "1583133621197-02/03/2020_15:20:21",
      status: "1"
    },
    {
      date: "02/03/2020",
      ts: "1583135570542-02/03/2020_15:52:50",
      status: "1"
    },
    {
      date: "02/03/2020",
      ts: "1583135586272-02/03/2020_15:53:06",
      status: "0"
    },
    {
      date: "21-03-2020:17:35:08",
      ts: 1584783308231,
      status: "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the code I've tried with aggregation pipeline splitting the string with first '-' and take the first element which is epoch timestamp and save it to the same field to an existing array.

```
db.novelmodel.aggregate([
  {$match: {pin: "JAIN"}},
  {
    $project: {
    pin: 1,
     bioupdate: {
      $filter: {
         input: "$bioupdate",
         as: "bioupdateArray",

         cond: { $and: [
          {$arrayElemAt:[{$split:["$$bioupdateArray.ts", "-"]}, 0]}
           ] }
      }
   }
  }
},

  {$out:"novelmodel"}
]);
```

It gives me an error message:   `"errmsg" : "$split requires an expression that evaluates to a string as a first argument, found: double"`.I'm not sure how filter to take only the date which has delimiter  '-' in a string

Comment: You may want to use the `$map` aggregation operator _instead of_ the `$filter`. `$map` allows you replace the existing string value with the transformed value for all elements of the array.

Comment: @prasad_ do you have sample code to try it out, as i am quite new to MongoDB.

Comment: [$map examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#examples).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue should be the last document which has `ts` as type `NumberLong()` instead of string, which is what throwing an error, Try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** Re-create 'bioupdate' with updated data */
  {
    $addFields: {
      bioupdate: {
        $map: {
          input: "$bioupdate", // Iterate on 'bioupdate' array
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: [{ $type: "$$this.ts" }, "string"] }, // Check if 'ts' field in current object is of type string
              /** If YES, Split it & get first element from array, it will be string if you want to keep is as number convert using '$long' */
              {
                $mergeObjects: [
                  "$$this",
                  {
                    ts: {
                      $toLong: {
                        $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ["$$this.ts", "-"] }, 0]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              /** If NO, Just to make sure convert existing to long & merge with actual object & push entire object back to array */
              { $mergeObjects: ["$$this", { ts: { $toLong: "$$this.ts" } }] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DZ_TbCnuuQG)

Comment: **Note :** I've mentioned it's existing as `NumberLong()` but I think it's existing as double in your actual doc, So then end you can convert to double instead of `long` using `$toDouble`..

Comment: thanks, it worked like a charm, one last thing when i try to add this "{$out:"novelmodel"}" at the bottom of your code to save the new merged records, it emptied out all the other pins.

Comment: @JAVAProgrammer : what do you mean by emptied we’re going ‘addfields’ so entire doc should exist did you try with project instead?

Comment: I mean will it update the existing field ts with the number long after split? when i query again using find, it doesnt reflect the modified value?

Comment: @JAVAProgrammer : If you aggregation is successful `$out` as an end stage will completely drop the collection `novelmodel` if it already exists & re-create a new collection with same name with results of aggregation pipeline, Just in case if there is not collection with name `novelmodel` then `$out` will create a new collection. Did you look into results of aggregation before `$out` ?

Comment: hey thanks!!!!! thanks alot, it works, my bad, i did with one particular id using$match which causes only that particular id saved and the rest of it gone, later when i remove $match, it succesfully updated to all the ids. thanks alot, it works.